# Create (default) Buttons using the local translated Text in C#

Tags: c#, localization, dialogresult

i would like to create buttons by c#Script as DialogResult (e.G. DialogResult.Yes)
And the text of the button should be the local correct for the language of the user.

```
new Button() { Parent = d, Text = "Oui", DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes };
```

The Text Oui should be the same as the text on the "Yes" - button by creating a MessageBox with

```
MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
```

Can i easily read what the Yes-Button should contain in the current language?
(I want to look through all dialogresult as the displayed buttons should get dynamic.

Thank you

Comment: [Localize form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628548/localize-form-controls-from-one-file-in-class-library?answertab=active#tab-top). [Globalizing and localizing applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/globalizing-and-localizing-applications).  [Globalizing Windows Forms applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/globalizing-windows-forms)

Comment: http://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/ is great link on localisation/internatisation. I know this for asp.net MVC but I would be looking for similar approach Windows Form