# Resource File to change Language at Runtime

Tags: c#, localization, resources, globalization

I have a program with many subforms in which every forum has its own resource file. I am trying to localize them so ı can add 1 more language to them. My problem is when ı localize them and change every resource string  1 by 1. How can ı call the new strings for that resx? file with clicking a button.

Comment: Winforms? Sattelite assemblies? Changing label texts on form? If 3x yes than you need to reload your forms after changes (create a new instance), because resources are loaded in `InitializeComponent()` called in form constructor.

Comment: We need more information about what type of project are you developing. Is it Windows forms, WPF, ASP .NET or anything else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Localization and Resource Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719930/c-sharp-localization-and-resource-files)

Comment: I am checking them out will reply as soon as ı try. Thank you but ı tried many from here ı think they arent gonna work but ı have hope still.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but sadly they didnt work. I think ı am just hopeless from this point on .